# Adding the max min length property in telerik grid Textbox in insert mode

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik

I m using the mvc telerik grid.
  While adding the new record, it is getting textboxes, for those input controls, need to restrict max number of characters for ex: 20.

Please help me..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: By Telerik Grid, is this the grid from the extensions or Kendo UI grid?

Comment: telerik extensions and not kendo UI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the id of the particular of the column ( for ex: codeId) and add the property of maxlength onEdit client event.  The grid has an OnEdit client event for that event written a function javascript where it has the necessary prop included for the input fields.

```
$("#elementId").prop("maxlength",'your max length for restriction');
```